# How can we enable authentication for a kafka connect service?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

i am using this docker-compose.yml file in my local to setup confluent-platform.
[https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml]

We are using connect-service in 8083 port to pull the data from the external source system.

Now the requirement is to access this Kafka-connect service 8083 port we need enable some authentication(Basic,SSl....)

But our kafka cluster is having no authentication,it is open only.

we need to enable the authentication only in the connect-service.

i tried to add the following line in docker-compose

```
CONNECT_REST_EXTENSION_CLASS : org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension
KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/secrets/connect_jaas.conf
```

My connect_jaas.conf

```
KafkaConnect {
   org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.PropertyFileLoginModule required
             file="/opt/kafka/secrets/rest-credentials.password";
};
```

rest-credentials.password

```
random=pass123
```

But the above configuration is not working...!!!

is that possible to achieve the above scenario?

If yes can anyone let me know how to achieve the same?

Comment: i fixed this by following this link [https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/basic-auth.html#kconnect-rest-api](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/basic-auth.html#kconnect-rest-api)  but now i am facing another issue .. i started the connect-service with user: password as authentication username and password combination when i try to change it as user1: pass1 and restart the connect-service it is still stick to the old credentials,**new credentials are not updated**... any idea on this

Comment: If you are using docker, the file with the credentials is in the docker image, restarting the container will have no effect, the image should be creted again and then restart the container.